# OpenMP using a large amount of CPU even for "do nothing" operations

Tags: c++, g++, openmp

I've inherited a project that uses OpenMP and I've found that the application inexplicably uses a lot of CPU even when doing nothing. Eventually I narrowed this down to the OpenMP usage (removing it removed the CPU usage).

I was able to recreate this issue with a reduced code snippet (see below). I find that when I run this application on my machine, I get roughly 100% CPU usage even though nothing is being done. The compiler I used was g++ 9.4.0 on ubuntu, but I got the same behavior for g++ 7.

```
#include <thread>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>


int main() {
  constexpr size_t thread_count_ = 5;
  while (true) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count_)
    for (int i = 0; i < 0; ++i) {
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }
}
```

Any idea what OpenMP options I should look into to try to debug this?

Comment: There is something being done: openMP is starting and synchronizing and sleeping the threads over and over.

Comment: I was under the impression that OpenMP simply creates new threads when a section needs to be parallelized. I don't think it makes sense that creating 5 threads will use so much CPU. If I were to manually parallelize using std::thread, I find less than 1% CPU usage.
If you're saying that this amount of overhead from OpenMP is normal, then I have no choice but to conclude that it's completely useless.

Comment: My prior comment was speculation. But I think it's not that OpenMP has high overhead, it's merely that it has high overhead *relative to an empty loop*. *If* I'm right, then implementing the same thing with `std::thread` would have roughly the same overhead.

Comment: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/openmp-dev/2017-September/001835.html Apparently this is done to make existing code keep running fast

Comment: Try to tweak the [`OMP_WAIT_POLICY`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse55.html) environment variable. Besides, please note that specifying `num_threads(...)` in the loop in such a use-case is generally a bad practice. You should use the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. This is much more flexible during the development stage of applications but also for end-users. Using a fixed amount of threads is generally the road for poorly-designed applications unless you know exactly where the application will be executed (and is unlikely to change).

Comment: By the way, a OpenMP runtimes need to recreate threads if `num_threads` is specified and changes. Some OpenMP runtimes can recreate threads even when the value does not change. However, AFAIK, GCC should not do that in up to date versions (GCC 9 is not very new but not so old either). Also please note that OpenMP runtimes needs to initialize several data structures so for parallel programs to be fast (eg. ICVs), they also need to share the work and perform synchronizations which is pretty expensive, especially on massively parallel platforms (eg. computing servers).

Comment: If the above information are not enough to solve your problem, then you should use a profiler (if possible one that can support profiling OpenMP applications). If you do not know any, you can start with VTune on x86-64 platforms (for Linux+Windows).

Comment: I set OMP_WAIT_POLICY to passive and it fixed the problem like magic. Are there any downsides to this change I might want to be aware of?

Comment: I have compiled your example with gcc 12 on a Intel Mac, and it does not consume any CPU.